# Why does the background image only appear after the window is resized?

Tags: java, image, swing

I'm creating a simple window with a background image by Swing java library.

The problem is :background image appear only when you resize window.

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import java.awt.MediaTracker;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

public class StartWindow {

JFrame frame;
private JButton button;
private JButton button2;

public void CreateStartWindow() {
    frame = Window.createwindow();
    Container container = frame.getContentPane();
    JpanelStart panel = new JpanelStart();
    container.add(panel);
    this.button = new JButton("Start");
    this.button2 = new JButton("Classifica");
    panel.add(button);
    panel.add(button2);
}

public void addActionListener(ActionListener al) {
    this.button.addActionListener(al);
    this.button2.addActionListener(al);
}

public void chiudi() {
    frame.dispose();
}
}

class JpanelStart extends JPanel {
private Image img;
private String path_img="img/sfondo.jpg";

public JpanelStart(){
img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(path_img);
loadImage(img);
}

private void loadImage(Image img) {
try {
  MediaTracker track = new MediaTracker(this);
  track.addImage(img, 0);
  track.waitForID(0);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
setOpaque(false);
g.drawImage(img,0, 0, null);
super.paintComponent(g);
     }
 }
```

### Window

```
public class Window extends JFrame {

public static JFrame createwindow() {//fare singleton

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Battaglia navale");

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(640, 640);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

    frame.setLocation(((int)dim.getWidth()-(int)frame.getWidth())/2,  
    ((int)dim.getHeight()-(int)frame.getHeight())/2);
    return frame;
         }
     ;
      }
```

Comment: We would need to see the source for `JpanelStart`, as I think the problem is somewhere in that class.

Comment: Class JpanelStart was included.

Comment: `frame.setLocation(((int)dim.getWidth()-(int)frame.getWidth())/2,  
    ((int)dim.getHeight()-(int)frame.getHeight())/2);`  ..is better to use.. `frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);` ..but it must be done before the frame is set visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible, call `setVisible` on the frame after you've added the components to it, otherwise you'll need to use `revalidate` and `repaint`.

Don't call `super.paintComponent` after you've painted something, as it's likely to clear `Graphics` context

Don't change the state of any component from with the `paintComponent` method, call `setOpaque` is bad from within the paint method is a bad idea, as the `Graphics` context has already being prepared assuming that the component was opaque

As has already being suggest, you should be passing `this` as the last parameter to `drawImage`, especially because of the way you load the image. Personally, I prefer to use `ImageIO` to load images, as it provides more details when the image fails to load....

Comment: Yes your suggest works. I've added frame.setVisible(true); at the end of class createstartwindow. But why?Can you explane me?

Comment: And if I would disable resizing?How can I do it?

Comment: I'm sure that questions or OPs here are cloned, last three weeks was about Thread & paint ... this week, especially today is about question this type of

Comment: Disabling resizing won't make much difference, and to be frank, I personally hate resizable windows as most of the time, they are too cramped to be useful. As to why the setVisible works this way basically comes down to how layout management and updating works. Generally speaking when adding new components to a top level container, you need to `revalidate` the component hierarchy.  Not 100% sure why, I just know you have to

Answer (score 1):

In this line...

```
g.drawImage(img,0, 0, null);
```

... you are passing `null` as the `ImageObserver`, so your component is not told to repaint when the image is loaded. You ought to pass `this`.

Comment: I've added this but the problem remain